# Elisp function to transform word at point

Tags: replace, keyboard-macros

How to write an elisp function that transforms the word at point?

Specifically, in the C++ code I am refactoring I have to replace tons of raw pointers into smart pointers. Say, for class `Foo`, I would move point to the start of the word `Foo`, call my function, and obtain `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.

So, the function I wish to implement would do these things:

1. Move point to the beginning of the word.
2. Insert hard-coded text (`std::shared_ptr<`).
3. Go to the end of the word.
4. Insert `>`.

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate. Please search tag `[query-replace]` or tag `[replace]`, and delete this question if you find it's a duplicate. Thx.

Comment: Of course, you could write and bind your own elisp command, but you might find it simpler to record, [save](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html) and bind a keyboard macro.

Comment: Sorry @Drew, I find your editing went a bit far. I do want to write an elisp macro. I do not want a complicated sequence of keystrokes which I have to remember and repeat anew in each session.

Comment: No, this has *nothing* to do with Elisp macros. Read the meaning of the tags. It sounds like you want a single key binding that does what you want. That's a keyboard macro or a command that's bound to a key. The meat of it is to make the change you want. How that's bound to a key is something else.

Comment: What Drew is talking about is that the word "macro" has two very different meanings in an emacs context.  What you want is a [keyboard macro](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Keyboard-Macros) which can automate repetitive key sequences.  An [elisp macro](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Macros) is a language construct that generates elisp code -- same word but very different meaning.

Comment: OK, changed text to make clear it is _not_ about a keyboard macro, but about an elisp function.

Answer (score 2):

## Creating Reusable Keyboard Macros In Emacs

There is a [concise article](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aaxw) on how to use keyboard macros in Emacs that I recommend you read.  The info in that article can be adapted to solve your specific problem like this:

- Place your cursor on the 'F' in a variable declaration of type `Foo`.
- Hit <kbd>C-x (</kbd> to start recording a macro.
- Type <kbd>s t d : : s h a r e d _ p t r < C-right ></kbd>
- Hit <kbd>C-x )</kbd> to stop recording the macro.
- Hit <kbd>M-x name-last-kbd-macro</kbd> to give the macro you just created a name.  For this example, I called it `std-shared-ptr`.
- Open your emacs configuration file.
- Type <kbd>M-x insert-kbd-macro</kbd> and tell it to insert `std-shared-ptr`.  The end result should look like this.

```lisp
(fset 'std-shared-ptr
   (kmacro-lambda-form [?s ?t ?d ?: ?: ?s ?h ?a ?r ?e ?d ?_ ?p ?t ?r ?< C-right ?>] 0 "%d"))
```

The `fset` function creates an interactive function named `std-shared-ptr`, and you can see what keys are going to be sent to Emacs by inspecting the [vector](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Vectors) it generated.

You can invoke this macro by hitting <kbd>M-x std-shared-ptr</kbd>, but if you're going to do this a lot, you might want to [bind](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands) this to something that's easier to type.  Also, we created this macro using `Foo`, but the <kbd>C-right</kbd> we hit while creating the macro should make it work for any type or class.

Comment: Instead of `C-<right>` (which is bound to `right-word`), I would recommend `C-M-<right>` (which is bound to `forward-sexp`): if the class name contains an underscore (which I iimagine is a a frequent occurrence), `right-word` would stop before the first underscore, wheres `forward-sexp`) would stop after the whole identifier. BTW, in my case, `C-M-<right` is preempted by my desktop environment, so I have to use `<ESC> C-<right>` instead.